# vuejs2 set value from php to vuejs2 with v-model

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2

hi i have this html code

```
<input type='text'   :value='{{$poss["pos_discount_value"]}}' v-model='pos_discount_value' />
```

and this is the vuejs2 code

```
data:{
    message:'', 
    item_search_array:false,
    arrayresults:[],
    total:0,
    quantity:1,
    discount:0,
    pos_discount_value:0,
},
```

now i define the pos_discount_value to 0 in vuejs2 code 
and in my html code its come from database as different value 
how to set the default value for pos_discount_value to value come from html not the 0 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use custom event on `created` hook

```
<input type='text'  @initDiscount='pos_discount_value={{$poss["pos_discount_value"]}}' v-model='pos_discount_value' />

created: function () {
    this.$emit('initDiscount');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i sloved it like this

```
<input 
  v-model="pos_discount_value"
  :run="!pos_discount_value ? pos_discount_value = {{$poss['pos_discount_value']}} : true"
/>
```

thanks guys

Comment: It looks more as cheat :) slyly